# INSERT Date/Time into SQL Server from python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to get data from XML (success) and then add that data to a SQL Server database (fail). My code is as follows:

```
def writeToSQL():
    server = 'server'
    database = 'database'
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    driver = '{SQL Server}'
    connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password)
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    SQLCommand = 'INSERT INTO QuartetSingleTesting (GURID, DataTime, xHorse, yHorse, zHorse, wHorse, Pay, [Source], LocalTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)'
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand, [argv[8], thisDataTime, argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], thisPayout, str(4)])
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

writeToSQL()
```

This now works.

Thanks for all advice.

Comment: Use prepared statements, don't paste sql

Comment: Please read https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#parameters !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do it something like this:

```
SQLCommand= 'INSERT INTO QuartetSingleTesting (GURID, DataTime, xHorse, yHorse, zHorse, wHorse, Pay, [Source], LocalTime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)'
cursor.execute(SQLCommand, [ argv[8] , thisDataTime , argv[1], argv[2], argv[3] , argv[4], thisPayout , str(4)])
```

I.e. for your paramters, use `?` to indicate that they will be supplied separately. Then you supply them in an array as the second argument to execute.

Comment: Updated question to reflect latest code and new error appears. Source is an integer field, but switching to 4 or int(4) for the last parameter does not change the problem

Comment: thisDataTime is of the form 2018-04-17 18:14:13. Could this be an issue?

Comment: @HKSaddler What are the data types of all your columns? What are the values of all the parameters? One common problem: an empty string cannot be converted to a number - if you want zero you have to pass `'0'`, if you want `NULL` you must pass `None`.

Comment: My final typo was to use argv[7] rather than argv[8]. argv[7] was a date, whilst argv[8] was a string. SQLServer was having the problem. Thank you for your help. The code works fine now.